# What is the best UI component to make user select a number from small range (1-12)?

Tags: gui-design, selection, android

I'm creating an Android application in which I want user to select a number from  1 to 12 (The standard in which user is studying). For this I've considered a dropdown with numbers 1 to 12 or a seekbar with range 1 to 12, but I think it'll not be good user experience to provide just 1,2,3.. numbers in dropdown or in seekbar.

What is the recommended component to use in such cases?

Comment: What does the value represent?

Comment: As mentioned, values are school standards (classes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options you could do here:

**OPTION 1**

Why not type it?

All the user needs to do is select the field and then type the number (with the majority of selections having just 1 number in anyway).

[image]

Entering numeric values on a number pad is generally more efficient for users.

There are only 12 options in a list which is probably too long for a drop down (on mobile especially) and given the characters they could be rather tricky to select, typing will be better.

**OPTION 2**

You could use something like this:

[image]

...and cap it at 12, or put a supporting note to tell users it caps at 12 (if needed), or simply put a 1 and 12 either side of the plus and minus to show both ends of the scale.

**OPTION 3** (which you stated)

A seek bar or sliders (scroll or bar based):

[image]

Personally I prefer the first two as they are more efficient and user friendly where as the latter has more room for error (particularly for users with large fingers or any accessibility issues).

Comment: I was avoiding text box because it causes invalid input possibility, so I need to put validations in my code. Anyways going with the textbox...thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sliders are tricky, requiring some fine-tuning. I can never seem to hit my target number on the first try.

Comment: @KenMohnkern me too I find them fiddly sliding through numbers, fields I find easier to just type from a keypad.

Answer (score 2):

You can show a dialog, when user clicks in that field , show 1 -12 values on that, on which user can just tap. In this way user can input desired value in just two taps.

Comment: I think you actually create the most frictionless experience with something like this. Especially if you already know that the value is going to be between 1 and 12.

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me, and usually aim for the most friction-less experience for the user, I'd go with the following:

1. UI: Auto focus the field
2. User: horizontal/vertical scroll to select numbers
3. User: tap Done/OK/Submit (whatever you use/want the user to do in)

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could use circle just like the default alarm/clock app does. The skeuomorphism doesn't work with your use case, but people will be acquainted with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the available space as well as type of field, if you have enough space you can have a slider to select a number, though I would prefer to have pulldown menu for input fields. It’s more intuitive.